# Having the following error when trying to implement a method of class using list in C++!

Tags: c++, database, string, iomanip

## Edit 1

Initial idea:

`MAIN.CPP`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Cars.h"
#include "Dealer.h"
#include "Manufacturer.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

//Instance variables for each class

string VIN = " ";
int miles;
string dealer = " ";
int price;
string vinCode=" ";

string manuCode = " ";
string manuName = " ";

string dealerName  = " ";
int zipcode;
string dealerPhone = " ";

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char command;

        //Cars vehicule;

    Manufacturer maker;
    Dealer dealership;
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;

    list <Cars> carsList;

        //Checks if the data file exists

    infile.open("database.txt", ifstream::in);

    outfile.open("database.txt", ios_base::app);

        //each command is a different program option

    cout << "Enter a command:" << endl;
    cin >> command;

    while (command!='q')
    {
        switch (command) 
        {
            case 'a':
            {
                cin >> command;
                    //adds a car
                if (command=='c')
                {
                        //creates a new car object and calls constructor
                    Cars *vehicule = new Cars();
                        //gets user input a assign then to variables 
                        //for the method calls

                    cin >> VIN >> miles >> dealer >> price;

                    // 1. this is were the compiler complains
                    vehicule.->addData(VIN, miles, dealer, price);

                    vehicule.addToBase(outfile);

                    carsList.push_back(vehicule);
                    list<Cars*>::iterator it;

                    for(it=carsList.begin(); it!=carsList.end(); it++)
                    {
                         cout << *it->getVIN() << endl; // compile error
                    }
                }
            break;
            }
        //new command to keep the while loop going
        cout << "Enter a command:" << endl;
        cin >> command;
        }
    }
        outfile.close();
        return 0;
}
```

`CARS.H`:

```
#ifndef CARS_H
#define CARS_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//Object that contains all information about cars (this is the class documentation)

class Cars {
    public:
        //class methods
        *Cars(){VIN=" "; mileage=0; dealership=" "; price=0;}
        void addData(string, int, string, int);
        void addToBase(ofstream&);
        string getVin(){return this->VIN;}
        int getMiles(){return this->mileage;}
        string getDealer(){return this->dealership;}
        int getPrice(){return this->price;}
    //private variables containing object information            
    private:
        string VIN;
        int mileage;
        string dealership;
        int price;
        string vinCode;
};


void Cars::addData(string identification, int mile, string dealer, int money)
{
    VIN=identification;
    mileage=mile;
    dealership=dealer;
    price=money;

    vinCode = VIN.substr(0,3);

    return;
}

void Cars::addToBase(ofstream& file)
{
    file << "c" << endl << VIN << endl << mileage << endl <<
            dealership << endl << price << endl;

    return;
}
```

## Edit 2

New version of what I have gotten so far:

```
#include "Car.h"
#include "Dealer.h"
#include "Manufacturer.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <list> 
using namespace std;

string VIN;
int miles;
string dealer;
int price;
string vinCode;

string manuCode;
string manuName;


string dealerName;
int zipcode;
string dealerPhone;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char command;
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;     
    list<Car*> carsList;

    //Checks if the data file exists
    infile.open("database.txt", ifstream::in);
    outfile.open("database.txt", ios_base::app);
    //Reads in user input
    cout << "Enter a command:" << endl;
    cin >> command;

    while (command != 'q') 
    {
        switch (command) 
        {
            case 'a':    //Add
            {
                cin >> command;
                if (command == 'c') //Add car
                {
                    cin >> VIN >> miles >> dealer >> price;
                    Car* vehicule = new Car(VIN, miles, dealer, price); //New pointer 
                    vehicule->addToBase(outfile);
                    carsList.push_back(vehicule);
                    list<Car*>::const_iterator iterator;

                    for (std::list<Car*>::const_iterator iterator = carsList.begin(),
                            end = carsList.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator) 
                    {
                        cout << (*iterator)->getVin();
                    }
                    //end of for loop
                }//end of if loop
            }//end of case loop
            break;
        }//end of switch loop
        cout << "Enter a command:" << endl;
        cin >> command;
    }//end of while loop
    infile.close();
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I still get an error:

```
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/project_1 make[2]:
*** No rule to make target `newcppsimpletest.cpp', needed by `build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/newcppsimpletest.o'.  Stop. make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2 make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

`Car.h`:

```
#ifndef CARS_H
#define CARS_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Car {
    public:
        Car();
        Car(string, int, string, int);
        void addToBase(ofstream&);
        string getVin(){return this->VIN;}
        int getMiles(){return this->mileage;}
        string getDealer(){return this->dealership;}
        int getPrice(){return this->price;}
        string getVinCode(){return this->vinCode;}

    private:
        string VIN;
        int mileage;
        string dealership;
        int price;
        string vinCode;
};

Car::Car()
{
    string VIN; 
    int mileage=0; 
    string dealership; 
    int price=0;
    string vinCode;
}
Car::Car(string vin, int miles, string carDealer, int dollars)
{
    string VIN=vin; 
    int mileage=miles; 
    string dealership=carDealer; 
    int price=dollars;
    string vinCode = VIN.substr(0,3); 
}
void Car::addToBase(ofstream& file)
{
    file << "c" << endl << VIN << endl << mileage << endl <<
            dealership << endl << price << endl; 
    return;
}
```

Comment: line 77                main.cpp:74:30: error: expected unqualified-id                                                                                                   vehicule.->addData(VIN, miles, dealer, price);

Comment: OK, should have said ‘*What's the error?*’.

Comment: by the way I apologize for the bad formatting, first post on Stack will reply any questions regardless

Comment: And what do you hope to achieve with `.->`? There are numerous issues in your code. Have you read a book or tutorial on C++?

Comment: the compiler suggested the implementation of .-> because Cars is a pointer

Comment: I doubt that. It might have suggested `->`, however.

Comment: The compiler would have suggested `->`, not `.->` (note the lack of the `.`). However, I would suggest (along with several others here, if I'm not mistaken) to instead change `Cars *vehicule = new Cars()` to `Cars vehicule;` (i.e., make it not a pointer)

Comment: I am still new at this so my coding skills and my code quality is not that good IMO, however I do wanna get better at this!

Comment: @Biffen I implemented a list of pointers the way many sources suggest and I still get that error. It looks fine to me.

Comment: I haven't read through your new code in detail, but the error message you get is due to the IDE you are using. Somehow, the file `newcppsimpletest.cpp` was not added to your project properly, and the compiler doesn't know where it is. Without more information, I can't be of too much help, unfortunately.

Comment: @madeluccar If you have a new question then please post a new question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
vehicule->addData(VIN, miles, dealer, price);
```

Instead of

```
vehicule.->addData(VIN, miles, dealer, price);
```

Comment: Man I feel dumb I did not caught that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You've declared vehicule as a pointer, but you're attempting to access methods with the '.' operator. You need to use '->' when working with pointers. Like: vehicule->addData(VIN, miles, dealer, price);

You'll need to update any code that references vehicule.

Comment: However I have another compiler error of type :    main.cpp:72:26: error: no viable conversion from 'Cars *' to 'Cars'  Cars vehicule = new Cars();    @Joel

Comment: @madeluccar `new Cars()` returns a `Cars*` and you're trying to assign it to a `Cars` variable. It's either `Cars* vehicule = new Cars();` or `Cars vehicule;`, depending on whether you want a pointer or not. It's not exactly recommended to use `new`, but if you do you should have a matching `delete` somewhere. I really recommend you read a book or something, there are numerous issues in your code.

Comment: @Biffen what other issues have you seen? And actually when you use new you should create a new object of type Cars

Comment: @madeluccar Issues of varying seriousness, of the top of my head: Implementation code in a header file (will cause problems later), odd variable scope, numerous cases of ‘pointer confusion’, strange class design, lack of `const`, all the inexplicable `" "` strings, memory leak. As for your second sentence: I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: @Biffen you are saying using new creates a pointer variable, but shouldn't that line create a new object of type Cars

Comment: @madeluccar `new Cars();` creates a new object of type `Cars` (it doesn't create a variable, I don't know where you got that) and gives you *a pointer* to it.

Comment: @Biffen what would the most effective way to create a list of objects, because I need to keep track os each object of type Cars and be able to get their instance variables by calling class methods.

Comment: @madeluccar Depends on what you mean by ‘*effective*’, but the common way is to create a class called `Car` (singular(!)) and a list of cars would be `std::list<Car>` (or `std::vector`; depends on what you plan to do with it). Unless you plan to create subclasses of `Car` you shouldn't need to (indeed you shouldn't) use pointers *anywhere*, and thus no `new`s or `->`s.

Comment: @Biffen and how can I create and traverse a list pf Objects so I can call each objects methods?

Comment: @madeluccar Google is your friend. There should be plenty of examples on the internet.

Comment: @Biffen would you look at it now? I still get an error but this one is different, the compiler doesn't even returns the location of the error in the main function.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I saw these two issues. You have declared `vehicule` as a pointer and allocated some memory like this.

```
Cars *vehicule = new Cars();
```

Then you're calling `vehicule` like this:

```
vehicule.->addData(VIN, miles, dealer, price);
vehicule.addToBase(outfile);
```

Strike the above.

The calls should be:

```
vehicule->addData(VIN, miles, dealer, price);
vehicule->addToBase(outfile);
```

While this seems like a small piece of code, it is always advised that, once you're done allocating, you should deallocate the memory.

Since, you add `vehicule` in the list, `carsList`, after the work is completed, do clean up the list.

You can do that, like this:

```
carsList.clear();
```

Hope this helps, You sound like you're new to this. So, trying to be as detailed as possible.

Comment: `carsList` will clear its own memory, what's more worrying is the `new` without a `delete`.

Comment: Your point about new and delete is correct. 

But, a clear becomes relevant if there are repeated calls  and he is using a push_back. 

Anyhow, for basic code, the precautions are meaningless , since, program stops execution immediately.

Comment: You really need to format the code in your answer to make it readable

Comment: Sorry, A little new to stack overflow. Come here once in a  blueMoon.

Comment: @UmashankarDas Why are you mentioning deleting pointers inside a list? OP hasn't got any lists of pointers.

Comment: @Biffen - What about this line? 

list <Cars> carsList;

Comment: @UmashankarDas That's a list of objects. A list of pointers would be `list<Cars*>`.

Comment: @Biffen Thanks. I was trying to do this as a pointer implementation. Would it not be a good idea to learn pointers instead of scaring people away from it?

Comment: @UmashankarDas It is my, and many others', opinion that pointers should be avoided. If pointer-like functionality is necessary then one of the smart pointer implementations should be used. But I don't see what any of this has got to do with lists of pointers.

Comment: I understand a bit about pointer funcionality, I mean I tried to implement a List of Objects but its still returning an error about not being able to transform a pointer to an object list, but I don't understan where I'm trying to do this is the code @Biffen